# Reading secular books on shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, books-generally

Which prominent halakhic authorities permit (or forbid) the reading of secular books, magazines, and newspapers from Friday evening until Saturday nightfall?  Why?  Is it *uvda dechol*?  What if it is an *oneg* for me to read something that is not inherently Jewish?

(I am not asking for psak, I am just interested in learning all of the opinions on the matter.)

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9936/759

Comment: The 39 Melachot by R' David Ribiat is perfect for this kind of question. He usually brings all the relevant opinions in his extensive footnotes.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28910

Answer (score 7):

I will summarize three positions I have read on this.

**1. Artscroll**

Artscroll has ruled (in *Limud Yomi: A Daily Dose of Torah* ed. 1 vol. 7) that it is forbidden to read business texts, including advertisements and billboards (p. 91) and newspapers (p. 108); but permitted reading books of secular knowledge (p. 99). They cited no sources except Shulchan Aruch 307:14, who permits reading letters which may contain vital information, and R' Moshe Feinstein (no source), who says this ruling doesn't apply nowadays.

**2. Shemiras Shabbos Kehilchasah**

This is the position of Shemiras Shabbos Kehilchasah (ch. 29): It is forbidden to read letters unless he hasn't previously read them, any business documents (#45); but permits reading newspapers "me'ikar hadin" except not the business sections, and he discourages it anyway (#46), and permits "books of learning" (sounds like Artscroll's "books of secular knowledge") but discourages it again (#47). He permits reading non-business bulletins, but not bulletins of deaths (#48). He quotes sources for everything.

**3. Shulchan Aruch**

The [Shulchan Aruch (307:17)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14171&pgnum=208) rules that it is forbidden to read anything but Torah on Shabbos, but quotes a "yesh mi shematir" (Ramban and Rashba) to read books of secular knowledge (as above). The Mishnah Brurah there writes that although the practice is to follow the "yesh mi shematir," it is better to be stringent.

Comment: And where did Artscroll get his semicha from?

Comment: It annoys me that they never quote sources, but they might have had a source.

Comment: Acharon acharon chaviv? :)

Comment: I actually wrote them in the order of how close the respective books were to me.

Comment: @ba Does the book at least have a listed author?

Comment: @ba (@DoubleAA) - Or rabbinical approbation saying that the printed information therein is kosher?

Comment: @ba - It is unrelated to the main topic of this question, but is the Rashza saying that those synagogues who read off a list of the anniversaries of members who have passed away before Mourner's Kaddish are doing something wrong?

Comment: @AdamMosheh Tircha DeTzibbura.

Comment: @DoubleAA I had assumed that the label "Artscroll" would be enough for you to decide whether you would hold by it; however, I will copy the information: The editor is "R' Yosaif Asher Weiss, Rosh Yeshivas Ohr Hadaas, Staten Island, who is also a distinguished editor of the Schottenstein editions of the Talmud[s] Bavli and Yerushalmi." It says that the halachah sections are from R' Simcha Bunim Cohen (but gives no information). [(Book)](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/ddset.html). (@AdamMosheh It seems to me that it is only prohibited when there is a suspicion that it might lead to erasing.)

Comment: since there doesn't seem to be any version of shemirat Shabbat Kehilchata online, can you list some of the sources he brings?

Comment: Sources (no se'if numbers listed because there are too many quoted): Shulchan Aruch OC 307; MB there; Daas Torah there (I have never heard of that book); Aruch HaShulchan there; Orchos Chaim there; and Ketzos HaShulchan in Badei HaShulchan 107.

Comment: Do we have any indication if RMF and RSZA's tendency towards stringency was due to the prohibition on reading secular material on Shabbat or to encourage people to spend Shabbat learning Torah?

Answer (score 6):

In Ketzos HaShulchan volume 4, R' Avraham Chaim Na'ah [(Badai HaShulchan 107:43)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7723&pgnum=37) brings the ruling of R' Yaakov Emden [Responsa 306 of She'elat Ya'avetz] that reading publications that have in them discussions of business is forbidden on Shabbat.

R' Avraham Chaim Na'ah explains that this refers to even intending to read just the news (which is technically permitted on shabbat, since it is necessary to know what's going on and brings one pleasure to read it - and pains one not to read it) and skipping over the business parts, since it is impossible to make sure you don't read the business parts at all.

[Although he doesn't discuss this explicitly, I think advertisements might fall under the category of business. If so, one couldn't read any publication that had advertisements, since it is impossible not to see them]

Based on this, R' Na'ah originally thought to permit reading publications made by Bnei Torah which don't have business in them at all, but are made to strengthen Torah observance. R' Na'ah concludes however, that one shouldn't even read those publications on Shabbat, since sometimes when one reads them he is pained by the plight of Orthodox Jewry around the world, and it is [forbidden to discuss/read about matters that pain you on Shabbat](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7723&pgnum=34).

R' Na'ah then says that all this is talking about publications that are made by Torah Observant people. Other publications include many things that are forbidden to read even during the week, such as heresy, frivolity, etc. And just like on Shabbat, one can't say he'll only read the "kosher" sections, since it is impossible to limit what you see that way. [makes me wonder what he'd say about the internet]

Answer (score 1):

The following is to address the question "why" in the OP.   Some contemporary positions are already brought in another answer.

There are three concepts involved:

(a) reading, even looking at, mundane writings, etc. in Shabbos - a Rabbinic prohibition based on the concern that you might correct them.

(b) a prohibition on learning secular subjects in general - which where/if prohibited, is prohibited during the week as well.

(c) muktza - the writings, books, documents etc., forbidden in this way become muktza in Shabbos.

And, there is a leniency that not everyone follows:

(d) books of wisdon, knowledge, medicine - *some* say you can read them in Shabbos, which implies that you can read them during the week.

These are the essential concepts.   The Shulkan Aruch elaborates on lists in shul, personal guest lists, menus, attending theaters (mushav letzim), assembling your telescope, greetings,  letters from outside the tehum, history books that a person might read to learn the language, and so forth.

Notably, your question about enjoying the news is in the Shulkan Aurch, too.

Recommended reading:

Shulchan Aruch Harav, 307:21-31, which is now available in English,  provides an especially clear exposition of the foundational concepts and examples.