# Reading a newspaper

Tags: halacha, publications, chol-weekday, secular-culture

Are there any works that discuss the permissibility of reading secular newspapers on a weekday? The Ketzos HaShulchan ([Badei HaShulchan 107:43](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7723&st=&pgnum=37)) holds that it's forbidden:

> Other [i.e. not Torah] newspapers in our generation are pretty much all against G-d and His anointed and are full of dirty jokes, heresy, and atheism, unfortunately, and even on a weekday it is forbidden to read them. Even if someone only wants to read the news part brought in the newspapers, it's still forbidden, lest he continue to read the other bad parts ... [Someone who reads them] transgresses "Don't turn to the idols" and strengthens his yetzer hara against himself ... Many people stumble in this area because they don't impart to themselves the enormity of the prohibition; someone who cares about his soul should distance himself from them, because these newspapers have made many dead fall.

Shmiras Shabbas KeHilchasah (second edition, ch. 21 note 117) quotes this source and doesn't bring a dissenting view.

The practice seems to be to read newspapers. I was wondering if there was a discussion of this in the modern poskim. (It's said that the Netziv would read the newspaper on Shabbas, but his position isn't clear — we don't know his exact reasoning. I'm looking for modern poskim who specifically speak about the issue and aren't just quoted as having read it or say it as a side point so I can see their reasons, etc.)

It was also asked about [Reading a newspaper on Shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6310/reading-a-newspaper-on-shabbat), but this is dealing with weekdays.

Comment: I wasn't aware there was debate about what the Netziv's position was. What emergency could there possibly have been anyway? Here you can read what the Netziv's nephew (primary source!) wrote about the Netziv's reading newspapers: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48316&st=&pgnum=122

Comment: @DoubleAA It's true that most likely there was no emergency (though I didn't know where the original source was to check). However, he doesn't discuss why it's permissible

Comment: Newspaper in the past were more like the magazines of today. Modern newspapers are mostly free of that stuff, and try to just have the simple news, so people are more OK with reading them. People often don't read popular magazines for exactly this reason.

Comment: Though Rabbi Epstein does seem to be saying that it was only Jewish newspapers that he read (about Torah and "Yisrael" — Jews, or maybe even settlers in Palestine?)

Comment: Here are t'shuvos that discourage newspaper reading _in passing_: [Iggres Moshe YD 2:76](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&st=&pgnum=141), [Minchas Yitzchok 3:79](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1598&pgnum=131). Not posting as an answer because the question specifically asked for direct discussions of the subject.

Comment: The last part of the statement you translated as _"have shot tons of soldiers"_  is actually a quote from Mishlei 7:26 - "‫רבים חללים הפילו‬
" http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2807.htm#26 -- Literally translated as http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16378/showrashi/true _"For many are the dead that she [i.e. the heart] has felled"_ , or _"For she hath cast down many wounded;"_ Basically saying (I think) that the heart has led astray many vulnerable people, and as such, one should not follow after it. Or in this case, don't read the newspaper because it has lead many astray.

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/25772

Comment: @DoubleAA Here is a good article about the dispute over the Netziv's position on reading newspapers on Shabbos, even within his own family, and attempts to censor the opinion that newspapers are permitted reading.  http://seforim.blogspot.com/2014/03/the-netziv-reading-newspapers-on.html

Answer (score 3):

למה לי קרא? סברא הוא

It is logical that a person should know about the world about him. In some communities, fencing off the world is an ideal, and you would expect to find explicit teshuvot against reading of newspapers. But in other communities, this would not even rise to the level of a question, such that **of course** one may read the news. And it would then be implicit in their actions, such as in the actions of the [Netziv](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7723&st=&pgnum=37). Lack of explicit teshuvot permitting is meaningless.

But here are [some explicit statements](http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5766/terumah.html#), as regards reading on Shabbos, but if on Shabbos it is permitted, then certainly during the week:

> QUESTION: Is it permitted to read the general news section of the newspaper on Shabbos [and Yom Tov]?
>
> DISCUSSION: Reading the general news section of the newspaper - including news, politics or stories of general interest, and advertisement or business news that have no bearing on the finances or shopping needs or plans of the reader, are a subject of dispute among the poskim. We find three basic opinions:
>
> - Many hold that reading this type of material is included in the Rabbinical edict against reading non-business documents and is forbidden to be read.(13)
> - Others hold that if one enjoys reading these type of articles then it is permitted to do so. These poskim maintain that the Rabbinical edict against reading non-business documents does not include enjoyable reading material.(14) Mishnah Berurah, however, does not support this position.(15)
> - Some poskim hold that while it may be permitted to read certain parts of the newspaper, reading a newspaper should be strongly discouraged since it is extremely difficult to avoid the advertisements or other parts of the paper which are forbidden to be read.(16) But other poskim, however, permit the reading of a newspaper as long as one makes a conscious effort to avoid the forbidden sections.(17)
>
> The following is a free translation of guidelines given by Harav N. Karelitz(18) on this subject: "While a ben Torah and his family should avoid reading a newspaper on Shabbos altogether, we do not object to those who are lenient and read the permissible parts of the newspaper. This is especially true with regard to women, children and those who do not engage in the study of Torah [who require a kosher alternative so that they will not come to engage in idle or forbidden talk or worse]; we definitely should not object to their reading the permissible parts of the newspaper."
>
> One should consult his halachic authority for guidance as to how he should conduct himself in this matter.

You could then refer to footnotes 14,17, and 18:

14 See Magen Avraham 301:4 and Peri Megadim; Ya'avatz 1:162; Kalkeles Shabbos 33; Tehillah l'David 301:1; Da'as Torah 307:15.

17 See Da'as Torah 307:16, Shemiras Shabbos K'hilchasah 29:46. See also Igros Moshe O.C. 5:22-3 who writes that business newspapers should not be read.

18 Ayil Meshulash on Shitrei Hedyotos, pg. 79, 83 and 210, and in Menuchah Shleimah, 2.

Comment: I would add that if there are teshuvot forbidding newspaper reading on Shabbas, they would implicitly permit reading during the week (unless that's specifically mentioned).  Otherwise why ask the question?

Comment: +1 for the "explicit statements". But why "It is logical that a person should know about the world about him"?

Comment: thanks. what do you mean "why"? למה לי קרא? סברא הוא. This is the sort of implicitly obvious thing that it is an exercise in futility to try to explain and prove.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman Because the level of the issur might vary. For instance, eating pork on Yom Kippur violates the fast of Yom Kippur.

Comment: I agree with Charles Koppelman. Especially if those who assur on Shabbat are silent about an issur during the week. This seems like a prohibition invented by some, but not all, Acharonim.

Comment: What are you saying the "svara" is: That a person needs to know what's going on around him, or that since the poskim permit it on Shabbas they must permit it on a weekday? (Note that Rabbi Na'eh himself, whose opinion I cited in the question, founded the newspaper [HaModia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HaModia))

Comment: @ba the former, plus the topic in general.

Comment: But then how is it that Rabbi Na'eh forbids it if he is *obviously* (סברא) wrong (I think the tshuvah he wrote came before he founded HaModia)? I would understand if there's a difference in opinion, but to hang it on סברא seems to be extreme, since it would imply that Rabbi Na'eh's opinion is contradicted by something as simple as סברא

Comment: Horayot talks about the difference between גמיר and סביר. Not everyone who is גמיר is also סביר, and vice versa. But seriously, for different sociological subgroups, approaches are axiomatic, and aren't subject to textual proofs. it is an obvious sevara, **once** you accept certain axioms. for modern orthodox (and other Orthodox groups), for example, the idea that people should be ignorant about the world (including science, world-events,  politics so as to know how to vote, etc.) is ridiculous, since the ideal is to engage and incorporate.

Comment: Rabbi Gedaliah Anemer, zt'l, Founder and Rosh HaYeshiva of Yeshiva of Greater Washington, and rav of Young Israel Shomrai Emunah in Silver Spring, was known to read the news section of the Washington Post on Shabbos, and sometimes commented on that day's news in his Shabbos address from the bimah (on the rare occassions he spoke about current events).

Answer (score 3):

I thought you might be interested in [this interview](https://onthemainline.blogspot.com/2010/09/how-r-moshe-feinstein-wrote-responsa.html) with R Moshe Tendler, the son-in-law of R Moshe Feinstein, where he says that, not only was RMF reading newspapers every day, but it was actually critical to giving him a view on societal factors which were important in him deciding *halacha*. Doesn't mean newspapers are good for all of us though - and Yiddish newspapers of the time are not today's newspapers.

> My shver was uniquely sensitive to society. Despite what they write in
>   all the books about him, my shver never failed to read the Yiddish
>   newspaper – either the Tog in the early years or the Morgn-Zhurnal
>   later on – cover-to-cover every single day. People publish that he
>   would walk down the street and avert his eyes when he passed by
>   newspaper stands. There are a thousand talmidim of his who will
>   testify, “I bought the paper and handed it to him in the lunchroom in
>   the yeshivah,” but it does not make a difference for some people –
>   they do not want to hear that.
>
> Even when he was not well and the doctor insisted that he must lie
>   down to sleep for an hour, he would go home, put on a bathrobe, and
>   smuggle a newspaper into the bedroom so that his wife would not see
>   it. He sat there reading the whole time, rather than sleeping.
>
> I used to ask him, “Why do you read this chazeray (junk)?” He would
>   respond to me, “Dos iz mayn vinde” – this is my window [to the world].
>   He understood society and his piskei Halachah show that. He used to
>   say, “People think that because I’m aware of society, I became a
>   meikel (lenient decisor). What do they want me to do – paskn
>   incorrectly? I’m not a meikel – I paskn the way it has to be. The
>   Halachah takes into account societal factors.” This willingness to be
>   exposed to society made his teshuvos more meaningful and more
>   acceptable.

[Here is a picture of him reading a newspaper](http://parsha.blogspot.com/2014/06/did-rav-moshe-feinstein-read-newspapers.html):

[image]

However I have now seen the following in R Shlomo Aviner's book [Rabbenu Ha-Rav Tzvi Yehudah Ha-Cohain Kook](https://www.ateret.org.il/uploads/files/Rabbenu%201-224.pdf) (p. 186)

> When a student asked our Rabbi (R Tzvi Yehudah Ha-Cohain Kook) if he should read the newspaper, our
>   Rabbi responded that he should not. The student said: "But isn’t this
>   the Yeshiva of Klal Yisrael [the entirety of Israel] and we need to
>   know what is happening in the Nation?" Our Rabbi responded: "When you
>   are a Torah giant of Klal Yisrael then you can read the newspaper."

Comment: That's an interesting article, especially in light of Menachem's comment which linked to Rabbi Feinstein's teshuva with a negative view of newspapers. I think you're right that it doesn't answer the question, because I wasn't looking for anecdotes as much as for sources that deal seriously with the question of whether reading a newspaper is permitted or not; but answers about Jewish newspapers are fine too. I see no reason why it shouldn't be a comment if you think it's worth deleting.

Comment: R. Rakeffet has mentioned several times that R. Moshe Feinstein read the New York Times every day.

Comment: Anyone able to make out the name of the newspaper in the photo?

Answer (score 1):

[R. Yisrael Meir Kagan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_Meir_Kagan) writes very strongly against reading newspapers. He objects to them because they are responsible for hundreds of lost hours of Torah study, and they spread [lashon hara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lashon_hara), rechilus, and discord.

**[Zechor L'Miriam Chapter 23](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14237&st=&pgnum=47)**

> ולמשל קריאת העיתונים שנתרבו מאד בזמנינו ורבו כיום מאד הקוראים אותם
>   והנה איך לא יבלה האדם הקוראם על כל פנים שעה אחת ביום על קריאתם ולפעמים
>   כיון שהוא נודע לכל כי הוא קורא ויודע חדשות העולם נמצאים כמה אנשים
>   ששואלים אותו מהנשמע והוא מתחיל לספר להם מכל דבר בפרוטרוט ובין כך ובין
>   כך הוא מבטל עוד כמה זמן על זה וישנם עוד הרבה אנשים שלא די להם בקריאת
>   עתון אחד אלא קוראים שנים שלשה או ארבעה עתונים מכל מין ומין ומבלים על
>   זה כמה שעות ביום והנה במשך שנה שלמה יצטרפו כל השעות הללו ויעלו להרבה
>   מאות שעות שעברו עליו בהבל וריק ללא תועלת לא לגוף ואין צריך לומר לנשמה
>
> וכל זה הוא רק אודות הביטול תורה בעצמו המגיע מקריאת העתונים והנה מצוי
>   הרבה שנמצאים פעמים בהם דברי ליצנות ולשון הרע זה על זה ורכילות ומחלוקת
>   אלו עם אלו ולולא נמצאו קוראים ומקבלים לזה כי אזי לא הדפיסו אותם ודבר
>   זה נעלם מכל שכולם יהיו נתפסים על זה לדין בבואם ליתן דין וחשבון לפני
>   כסא הכבוד

R. Kagan discusses this issue in a letter as well, and there he is much harsher. In addition to what he wrote above, he adds that newspapers are full of mockery, uncouth language, and heresy. He states that it is forbidden to read them even during the week (let alone on Shabbos). He describes the great sin in very strong language, and asserts that all our troubles are a result of reading newspapers:

**Likutei Ma'amarim U'michtavim # 42**

> הנה רבים שאלוני הרי אנו מאמינים בד' ובהשגחתו הפרטית ושהוא עשה ועושה
>   ויעשה לכל המעשים וכל הסיבות והמאורעות המתהוות בעולם המה מד' וכדכתיב
>   בקרא (עמוס ג') "אם יתקע שופר בעיר וגו' אם תהיה רעה בעיר וד' לא עשה"
>   וא"כ מה זאת עשה אלהים לנו הלא בימינו אלה נתרבו סיבות ומאורעות נוראות
>   שלא נשמעו כמותם מעולם ובודאי צדיק ד' בכל דרכיו ולא חשיד קוב"ה דעביד
>   דינא בלא דינא וא"כ נחקורה בשל מי הרעות הללו עלינו הלא כלל ישראל טובע
>   בים של צרות ומצוקות חסרון הפרנסה נוראה למאד אמנם כאשר נתבונן היטב
>   ונעמיק בדברי חז"ל נמצא את הסבות שגרמו לנו את כל הצרות והמצוקות שאנו
>   סובלים ואביא כאן רק מאמרים אחדים שהם לבדם מראים לנו בעליל שבדין באות
>   עלינו כל הצרות
>
> איתא בחז"ל (ע"ז י"ח) א"ר אלעזר כל המתלוצץ יסורים באים עליו שנאמר
>   (ישעי' כ"ח) ועתה אל תתלוצצו פן יחזקו מוסריכם (ופי' יסוריכם) ורב קטינא
>   אמר מזונותיו מתמעטין שנאמר (הושע ו') משך יד את לוצצים (ופירש"י הקב"ה
>   שהוא הפותח יד לזון את הכל מושכה מן הלוצצים) ור' תנחום בר חנילאי אומר
>   שגורם כליה לעולם שנאמר (ישעי' כ"ח) ועתה אל תתלוצצו וגו' כי כלה ונחרצה
>   שמעתי ור"א אמר תחילתו יסורים וסופו כליה הרי חזינן כמה גדולה כח הליצנות
>   שמלבד ענשו הנורא של האדם לעוה"ב הרי כל אלו העונשים המה בעוה"ז שהמה
>   בודאי רק התחלה לעונשו עוה"ב
>
> והנה בעוה"ר המציא היצה"ר שהוא השטן תחבולה חדשה להחטיא את אחב"י בעון
>   של ליצנות ולגרום הסתלקות ההשפעה מהעולם והוא ע"י קריאת העתונים שנתרבו
>   מאד בזמנינו שנמצא בהם דברי ליצנות ולשה"ר ורכילות ומחלוקת ודברי כפירה
>   ומינות ואם לא היו נמצאים קוראים ומקבלים כ"כ לזה כי אז לא הדפיסו אותם
>   ודבר זה נעלם מכל שכולם יהיו נתבעים ע"ז לדין בבואם ליתן דו"ח לפני ממ"ה
>   הקב"ה הן המדפיסים והן המוכרים והן הקוראים אותם וענין זה נעשה להרבה
>   מאחב"י דבר הכרחי למאד עד שאי אפשר להם להיות יום אחד בלא עתון וכמה שעות
>   ביום מבלה האדם על קריאתם ועוד שמעתי שערורי' נוראה שימי השבתות והמועדים
>   שנקבעו להיות ימי מקרא קודש להרבות בהם בדברי תורה ויראה כדכתיב זכור את
>   יום השבת לקדשו נהפך בעוה"ר שגבר השטן והנהיג שבכל עש"ק ויו"ט מדפיסים
>   אותם כפלים מאשר מימות החול והעורכים משתדלים אחרי כל מיני ליצנות ושחוק
>   וניבול פה ומדפיסים אותם בגליונות של עש"ק ועיו"ט והרבה מאחב"י מבלים את
>   כל יום השבת הקדוש בקריאת ענינים האלו אוי לאזנים שכך שומעות ואוי לעינים
>   שכך רואות מה שנעשה בעוה"ר שמזלזלים כ"כ בקדושת השבת והחגים, שאפילו בחול
>   אסורים לקרות בהם משום מושב לצים ועונש הליצנות גדול למאד כנ"ל ועונש זה
>   נאמר גם על המדפיסים והעורכים שאפילו מי ששומע דברים כאלו ושותק אמרו
>   חז"ל שעליו נאמר זעום ד' יפול שם וכש"כ מי שהביא לכמה אלפים אנשים לכלל
>   זה והם חוטאים ומחטיאים את הרבים שאין מספיקין בידם לעשות תשובה ופליאה
>   גדולה לי על הכשרים שבאחב"י המאמינים בד' ותורתו ויודעים את חומר העון
>   שגם בהם נמצאים הרבה שנכשלים בזה ומתפתים אחרי דברי היצר ומבלים כמה שעות
>   ביום ע"ז הלא הם יודעים את חומר העון מדוע אינם שמים על לב את גודל העון
>   של ביטול תורה וגם העון המר של ליצנות ולא עוד אלא שיהיו נתפסים בעון
>   הרבים דההמון הפשוט בראותו שגם הכשרים לוקחים חלק בקריאת העתונים ממילא
>   מתירים גם לעצמם נמצא שהם גומרים להם לחטא זה ולולי שהיו קוראים בם כי אז
>   חדלו גם הרבה מההמון לקרותם ועוד גדולה תמיהתי עליהם הלא הם בעצמם מפילים
>   תחנונים ובקשות לפני הקב"ה בכל יום שישלח לנו את אליהו הנביא ומשיח צדקנו
>   באיזה פנים הם מבקשים בקשות כאלו האם יוכלו לקבל פני אליהו בשעה שהמה
>   עסוקים בשחוק וליצנות ודברים בטלים הזאת היא ההכנה שהמה מבינים א"ע
>   לביאתם הלא בושה וכלימה תכסה פניהם כשימצאם אליהו הנביא במצב כזה
>
> והנה לבד המכשלה גדולה הזאת נתבונן נא כמה ביטול תורה יש מענין זה משום
>   דבאותה שעה שהוא קורא את העתונים הרי הי' בידו ללמוד תורה ולקרות בספרים
>   המעוררים את האדם לתורה וליראה והדבר הזה הוא לא ביום אחד או יומים אלא
>   הדבר הזה חוזר ונשנה בכל יום ויום וחלק גדול מחיי האדם הולך אצלו לבטלה
>   על קריאת העתונים המלאים בשחוק וליצנות וניבול פה וכפירה ואם יטעון הטוען
>   הלא גם לפנים היו עתונים ומה היום מיומים אענהו אמת הדבר אבל לפנים היו
>   כל העתונים בלה"ק ולא היו מצויים כ"כ הקוראים וגם לא היו בהם דברי ליצנות
>   וניבול פה כ"כ כאשר בימינו אלה משא"כ בזמננו שהעתונים נדפסים בשפה
>   המדוברת וקטן וגדול ונער וזקן יכולים לקרותם רבה המכשלה מאד והיא היא
>   הסבה שנתמעטה ההשפעה העליונה מאתנו ועל ידה באות עלינו כל הצרות והמצוקות
>   הקורות אותנו ומה נואלו אותם האנשים המבקשים סגולות ותחבולות לפרנסה הרי
>   יש לנו עצה ותחבולה לפרנסה בזה שיזהרו מליצנות וכדומה הגורמים לחסרון
>   פרנסה
>
> ע"כ אחי ורעי הרוצה להנצל מעונש הקשה של העון המר הזה יתרחק בכל היכולת
>   מלקרות בעתונים כאלו שנמצאים בהם דברי ליצנות וניבול פה וכפירה וכ"ז
>   אפילו בחול אסור וביותר יזהרו בזה בשבתות ובמועדים שאותם הימים נקראים
>   ימי מקראי קודש ובשכר זה יתן לו ד' השפעה והצלחה במעשה ידיו ויזכה לכל
>   טוב בזה ובבא אייר תרפ"ח

Comment: Interesting source, but I was looking more for poskim who literally forbid it, even though distinguishing between poskim and books of musar is a little arbitrary. If he said that in Mishna Berura as law, it would be more insightful, considering that no one these days seems to care about this prohibition (if there is one)

Comment: @ba I added in a source where he explicitly says it's forbidden (though it's still not in a "halachic work").