# Lashon Hara And News articles?

Tags: halacha, lashon-hara-slander

Is it considered Lashon Hara to read a news article on someone that has derogatory facts about him/her? List sources. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that a news article would be different from other sources?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94481/reading-lashon-harah-online

Answer (score 4):

The Chofetz Chaim wrote strong words against reading newspapers (see him quoted for instance [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/93794/11501)) because of *lashon hara* and *bitul Torah* amongst others.

In an [interesting interview](https://jewishaction.com/religion/jewish-law/discussing-journalism-jewish-law-rabbi-j-david-bleich/) of **R J. David Bleich** regarding Journalism and Jewish Law he **says that it is *lashon hara* to draw attention to derogatory facts to a broader audience that would otherwise has known it**

> In the body of his classic work devoted to lashon hara, the Chofetz
>   Chaim summarizes as black-letter law that, according to all Rishonim,
>   it is absolutely prohibited to cause such information to be
>   disseminated to a wider audience than would otherwise have been in
>   possession of those facts. Intent to draw the matter to the attention
>   of people who would otherwise have remained ignorant of that
>   information renders the communication lashon hara per se.

**However R Gil Student suggests** ([here](https://www.torahmusings.com/2013/03/readings-newspapers/)), based on the Chofetz Chaim and the writings of R Binyamin Cohen that

> **a critical reader would be allowed to read a newspaper that sometimes
>   contains lashon ha-ra**. If it regularly contains lashon ha-ra, then
>   your reading it is essentially tilting your head to hear. But if it is
>   there incidentally, you need not worry if you stumble across such a
>   forbidden article. However, you must maintain a skeptical attitude
>   toward the reporting, recognizing the limitations of journalism and
>   the need to refrain from judging the subjects based on such limited
>   evidence and without hearing both sides of the story.

See also [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/93956/11501) for details of R Moshe Feinstein reading the newspaper as a way to get up to date information to inform his halachic decisions,